# PHP/MySQL Program Outline

Tags: php, mysql, database, storage

I'm currently in the process of creating a website and want to know how you guys think I should go about storing my information.

I'm making a website which allows users to create an account and then enter/log in workout information each day that they can.

Each time they input a log, there are a few pieces of information they must include (ie. the date, the length of their workout, the type of workout, etc.). The website will then be able to supply them with graphs that analyze their data.

I'm coding using `php` and `mysql`. My question revolves around how I should store all the data for the website. I know I need a `mysql` table that will have a column for id, username, email, and password. However, I'm unsure how to store the daily logs.

Should I create an array for each field (ie. workout duration) and use `serialize()` to store it in the same `table` as the users? If so, how would I go about updating the array each time a log is inputed? Thanks.

Comment: Don't serialize, [normalize your schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) instead.

Comment: First - don't store the password; store a (salted) hash of the password. As for the second part - it depends a bit on how big things will get and what performance you need. Ask yourself what queries you will use, and how much work it will be to parse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use several tables for this, for example the tables:

- site_users
- site_workouts

That way you have all user data stored separately. In your workouts table, you would add a new row per record, and include a foreign key (user_ID) that links each row to a user. So you could match a list of workout logs to a single user.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I hadn't thought of this idea. I think it's what I'll do. Thanks!

Comment: If you have lots of similar data that needs to go somewhere, that's when you make a separate table for it. So users, workouts, etc. That's how I tend to think of it when designing something new. Just because it's in different tables, doesn't mean it isn't related! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice but personally I would use 2 sql tables:

User(id, username, email, and password)
Workout(user_id, date, workout_length, workout_type)

This way you can keep adding logs for users and recieve the data when needed.
You keep comptibility with alot of other services.

And process the sql records with php.